# getting the characters from FileInputStream

Tags: java

common code for 1 and 2

```
    String gt="hello master how the heck are you:";
    byte o[]=gt.getBytes();
    FileOutputStream aab=new FileOutputStream("first.txt");
    aab.write(o);
    aab.close();
    FileInputStream nm=new FileInputStream("first.txt");
```

1:::

```
      while((nm.read()!=-1)
      out.print((char)(nm.read());
```

2:::

```
      int y=0;
      while((y=nm.read())!=-1)
      out.print((char)y);
```

I want to ask why these two(1 and 2) are giving the different outputs.I have spend quality time in finding this but still I am unable to find .please help me if you can.  the expected output from 1 should be same as the 2 but 1 is giving unexpected output.please explain this ..

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
  1. while((nm.read()!=-1)
  2.   out.print((char)(nm.read());
```

bytes are read from the stream in two different places, but only one is printed:

- one byte (first) is read from the stream in line #1 (while),
- then next byte (second) is read in line #2 (print) - and **only this byte is printed**

And then a whole cycle repeats:

- next byte (third) is read in line #1,
- and subsequent byte (fourth) in line #2 - and **this one is printed.**

---

But here:

```
int y=0;
  while((y=nm.read())!=-1)
  out.print((char)y);
```

bytes from the stream are read only in one place - in `while` instruction, and all of them are printed.